# Getting discord access token[Discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

Im still trying to authorize my discord bot with my website with [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/) but i dont really understand how to get the access token.

My code

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 53134;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
 let responseCode = 404;
 let content = '404 Error';

 if (req.url === '/') {
  responseCode = 200;
  content = fs.readFileSync('../HTML/index.html');
 }

 res.writeHead(responseCode, {
  'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
 });

 res.write(content);
 res.end();
})
 .listen(port);
```

everytime I run this i get the'404 error' and I feel like its because of the missing access token

Comment: what url are you trying to reach?

Comment: **UPDATE** i fiqured it out like a week ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 404 = Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Error 403 = Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

So if you are missing access token the error would be 403, not 404.